# How to be sure the inserts are complete via linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have a table in 'my' server. I am connecting to a linked server and inserting data from my table to a table in the remote table via openquery. When the inserts are done I want to truncate my table (in my server). I am doing this in a procedure. I am checking if the linked server is available with sys.sp_testlinkedserver before the inserts. But what will happen if the linked server goes offline or become unavailable while I am inserting. Lets say there are 100 rows in my table and while the 50th row is being inserted to the remote table, the remote server goes offline or something goes wrong. How can I structure this so that I know that all my records are inserted to the remote table and if not all the records are transferred I will not truncate my 'local' table? (Both are SQL servers 2008 r2)

Comment: Maybe [distributed transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188386.aspx) is what you are looking for? I don't have any experience with them myself so I can't say for sure. In any case, a transaction is most likely what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you would need just one **single** `insert` statement, which transfers data from one server to the other.

You don't need "`openquery`" (what are you doing? Are you writing record by record in a loop? That's not necessary at all, and it will even be very very slow).

Well, your **single** `insert` statement is then a transaction. Either this transaction completes as a whole, or it fails. If it fails, you can catch the error, and do the truncate only when the insert is complete.

Comment: I am using openquery this way inside a procedure - `INSERT OPENQUERY([remote_server],'SELECT [a]
      ,[b]
      ,[c]
  FROM remote_db.remote_table')
  SELECT [a]
      ,[b]
      ,[b]
  FROM my_table` . Then I am truncating my_table.

Comment: @pinklotus You can just insert across two servers, like this: `insert into server1.db1.dbo.table1 (a, b) select x, y from server2.db2.dbo.table2 `    I'm doing transfers like this very often.

Comment: So this is a single transaction. So I am assuming I will put a try catch around it to check whether the insert was a success or not? Then if it didn't fail I can confidently truncate my table? - Just saw you other question - No I am not writing record by record. Not a loop. A simple insert - I am just nervous about truncating my table without knowing that all of my local table records are transferred to the remote server.

Comment: @pinklotus Yes, absolutely, you can totally rely on this. This is even one of the most central design principles of the sql server. A transaction must be **atomic**, i.e. either it completes as a whole, or it does not at all.  There is no "half work", this is strictly forbidden. Only all or nothing.

Comment: Ok just what I wanted to know. Salute SQLPolice.

Comment: @pinklotus BTW, I have experienced such situations, where a big transaction was interrupted. Most often due to out-of-disk space, but also due to server outage. And it is really pretty amazing: You might be sweating like hell, but the databases are totally stable. Nothing gets lost.

Comment: Ok one more question related question though. Isnt OPENQUERY a single  transaction as well? Cant I do the OPENQUERY statement inside the try catch and expect the same resutls?

Comment: @pinklotus Basically yes. However, please note that `openquery` is connecting via OLEDB, and this is normally used when you are connecting to other databases, like Oracle, DB2, SAP, etc. But when you are connecting to another sql server, then you simply don't need it. It is only adding another layer to your solution. I recommend to not use it in this case.